# Mathematical Symbols in r

Tags: r

I am wondering how you type the symbol for pi for the column name of a matrix in r. I known that using $\pi$ gives makes the symbol for pi show up in regular text, but I need the symbol for pi as the column name in my r chunk and when I try to type the symbol for pi using my keyboard R mark-down does not allow the file to knit to pdf.